# PHP: сеттеры-геттеры и магия, best practices.

Tags: php

Предположим, есть некоторый класс, который выполняет роль простой структуры:

```
class ProcessStatus
{
    protected $command;
    protected $pid;
    protected $running;
    protected $signaled;
    ...
}
```

Его дальнейшая судьба неизвестна, может, завтра нужно будет впихнуть кучу логики в геттеры, может, ему вообще нужны были бы публичные свойства, а не геттеры и сеттеры, но в данный момент решено все делать через protected-свойства. Остается вопрос с обеспечением доступа к данным, и тут есть три варианта:

а) Code -> Generate -> Getters & Setters: создать необходимые геттеры и сеттеры простыми методами `getX()` / `setX()`. Плюсы: автокомплит в IDE любой убогости, скорость. Минусы: невозможно разом переписать несколько геттеров/сеттеров.

б) написать автоматические геттеры и сеттеры через `__call()` и прописать их в `@method` в phpdoc-шапке. Плюсы: выглядит, как настоящие геттеры и сеттеры, проще поддерживать, описываются единым списком в шапке. Минусы: возможно, скорость, гибкость меньше, чем при отдельных геттерах и сеттерах, легко забыть описать нужный метод, или, наоборот, описать несуществующий, чтобы по-человечески совместить `getMixed()` и `isBool()`, надо солидно покорячиться.

в) написать прямой доступ к полям через `__set()` или `__get()`, прописать аналогично через `@property`. Плюсы: как в предыдущем + легко интерполировать в строках. Минусы: опять же, как в предыдущем, выглядит не очень интуитивно - если IDE видит свойство, то почему я не могу присвоить ему значение?

Все три варианта на самом деле отвратительны, но по ряду *параноидальных* причин мне не импонируют открытые свойства, поэтому приходится выбирать. Мне больше всего импонирует второй с `__call()`, но все равно есть чувство отвратного.

Есть ли какие-нибудь гайдлайны по этому вопросу?

Answer (score 1):

Можно быренько напилить некоторый класс болванку , чтобы можно было его накачивать данными и пользоваться ими в разрезе ОП

```
/**
 * Генерации обьекта структуры данных с типичным функционалом бин доступа get-set 
 * поддерживает общий интерфейс цепных запросов  
 * 
 * @example :
 * $this->query = object::create();
 * $string = $this->query->set("skin", "001")
 *                       ->set("zone" , "alabama")
 *                       ->set("len" , 1000)
 *                       ->getQuery();
 * 
 */
class objectData
{

    protected $queryParam = array();

    public static function create()
    {
        $obj = new self;
        return $obj;
    }

   /**
    * определить все элементы структуры данных из массива 
    * структура представляет собой простой массив
    * 
    * @param array $queryParam
    * @return object
    */
    public function setParam(array $queryParam)
    {
       $queryKeys = array_keys($queryParam);
       $this->queryParam = array_fill_keys($queryKeys, "");
       return $this;
    }

    public function set($property, $value)
    {
       $this->queryParam[$property] = $value;
       return $this;
    }

    public function get($property)
    {
        return $this->queryParam[$property];
    }

    /**
     * Прикрепить произвольную функцию к объекту
     * 
     * example : 
     * $this->query->randomQuery = function($self){
     *       $self->getQuery();
     * }; 
     */
     public function __call($name, $arguments)
     {
        if ($this->$name instanceof Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$name, array_merge(array($this), $arguments));
        }
     }
}
```

Далее эту болванку наследуем куда надо и расширяем чем надо , для выше описной задачи думаю может подойти.

Comment: *Далее эту болванку наследуем куда надо* - и теряем возможность наследования от полезных классов вообще.

Comment: Ну я же написал болванка , сверху может быть класс который реализует частности , а он в свою очередь используется базово . Не вижу тут какой-либо потери.

Answer (score 0):

Мне нравится подход в YII2:

```
class Object
{

.....

/**
     * Returns the value of an object property.
     *
     * Do not call this method directly as it is a PHP magic method that
     * will be implicitly called when executing `$value = $object->property;`.
     * @param string $name the property name
     * @return mixed the property value
     * @throws UnknownPropertyException if the property is not defined
     * @throws InvalidCallException if the property is write-only
     * @see __set()
     */
    public function __get($name)
    {
        $getter = 'get' . $name;
        if (method_exists($this, $getter)) {
            return $this->$getter();
        } elseif (method_exists($this, 'set' . $name)) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Getting write-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        } else {
            throw new UnknownPropertyException('Getting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Sets value of an object property.
     *
     * Do not call this method directly as it is a PHP magic method that
     * will be implicitly called when executing `$object->property = $value;`.
     * @param string $name the property name or the event name
     * @param mixed $value the property value
     * @throws UnknownPropertyException if the property is not defined
     * @throws InvalidCallException if the property is read-only
     * @see __get()
     */
    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $setter = 'set' . $name;
        if (method_exists($this, $setter)) {
            $this->$setter($value);
        } elseif (method_exists($this, 'get' . $name)) {
            throw new InvalidCallException('Setting read-only property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        } else {
            throw new UnknownPropertyException('Setting unknown property: ' . get_class($this) . '::' . $name);
        }
    }
.....
}
```

Его можно взять за основу и допиливать под свои нужды.

Comment: Не, это вряд ли подходит:

* Надо писать и магию, и реальные геттеры/сеттеры, в то время как достаточно чего-то одного.
* Все на свете должно наследоваться от единственного класса.